# Which Punctuation Do You Use For Quotations

Tags: punctuation, quotations, quotation-marks

Which one of these if correct, if I am trying to refer to a quote

> 'We're all a little bit gay' - Harry Styles

> "We're all a little bit gay" - Harry Styles

Comment: According to [this](https://www.thepunctuationguide.com/british-versus-american-style.html) it depends which side of the pond you are. But you could have looked this up for yourself.

Comment: @KateBunting as different sources say different things, I do not know which one(s) to believe...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are correct.  A particular publication might have a house style that prefers either single or double quotation marks.

The APA style uses double quotation marks, except when quoting material that contains quotation marks in which case the interior quote uses single marks:

> “We're all a little bit gay” - Harry Styles

> The reporter told me, “When I interviewed the Harry Styles, he said ‘we're all a little bit gay.’”